# GIT SSH connection issue

Tags: git, https, ssh, git-clone

I am trying to access a remote repo from the GIT bash on Windows 8.

I have been through the steps detailed at https://serverfault.com/questions/194567/how-to-i-tell-git-for-windows-where-to-find-my-private-rsa-key which ensure GIT is using the right public/private key.

Connecting and cloning a dir via https is not an issue. However doing so, means read/write/access rights on the files I push changes to gitlab/https only which means my team members cannot change the files.

Connecting via SSH, I am asked firstly for the passphrase for the key stored at /c/Users/bwimbush/.ssh/id_rssa. After entering that, I am then asked for "git@remoteserver.com's" password. I don't understand why I am asked for this password?

I can log into the git setup online using my google account, but that pw is not the pw it is asking for.

Can anyone help me understand why connecting via https changes read/write/access rights on the files, or why it is asking me for "git@remoteserver.com"'s password?

Comment: Have you checked that your server's ssh daemon configuration is correct? Generally when it asks you for a password is because the prefered authentication method (public/private key) has failed. You should post a snippet of what git prints when it fails to connect to give us more context.

Comment: permission problem might be due to `umask`?

Comment: It just says "permission denied." Then after it has failed 3 times, "write failed: the connection was aborted." "fatal: could not read from remote repository". Please make sure you have correct access rights and the repository exists

Answer (score 1):

Fire up Git bash window and run

```
ssh -i /c/Users/bwimbush/.ssh/id_rsa -v git@remoteserver.com 'git --version'
```

and see what it tells you about the authentication process taking place. (You could try adding more "-v"-s).  Pay close attention to those messages involving the word "pubkey".

Does this print anything fishy?